# Vue компонент во всех шаблонах без импорта?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, frontend, quasar-framework

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, что бы мой Vue компонент был доступен во всех шаблонах Vue, но при этом его не нужно было каждый раз его импортировать?
Использую Vue фреймворк `Quasar`.

Comment: Необходимо зарегистрировтаь его через `Vue.component()`

Comment: Сегодня постараюсь ответить развёрнуто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два варианта.

### 1. Зарегистрировать компонент через `Vue.component()`

Регистрация компонентов таким образом позволяет использовать эти компоненты во всех `Vue` шаблонах без дополнительной регистрации.
Пример кода:

```
import {LoaderSent} from "shared";
import {SunEditor}  from "shared";

Vue.component("LoaderWait", LoaderWait);
Vue.component("SunEditor", SunEditor);
```

Что бы в `Quasar-Framework` этот код отработал в нужное время его необходимо поместить в [boot секцию](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/boot-files).

### 2. Сделать автоматический импорт через webpack Provide плагин

Используем webpack [Provide](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) плагин.

Этот способ регистрирует в сборщике `Webpack` компоненты, позволяя не импортировать их каждый раз в каждом файле.

Пример кода в файла `quasar.config.js`:

```
build: {
  ...
  extendWebpack(cfg) {
                cfg.plugins.push(
                    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                        Vue: ['vue', 'default'],
                        sunImport: ['src/utils/sunImport', 'default'],
                        request: ['src/utils/request', 'default']
                    }));
  }
}
```

В этом коде мы регистрируем `Vue`, `sunImport` и `request` компоненты.

Примеры кода взяты с проекта [GitHub SunEngine](https://github.com/sunengine/SunEngine/tree/master/Client) / Client.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло

Comment: Пока не пробовал данный плагин. Работает ли он так, что делает ссылку, и потом когда время приходит - он только тогда его загружает, или он делает загрузку при старте приложения?

Comment: @Dmitry Это происходит на уровне сборки

Comment: Значит, с ассинхронностью такое не получится, если есть желание разбить проект на части, что бы это не был большой бандл?

Comment: Судя по твоим комментариям ты ищешь готовые решения. Программист это тот, кто может сам находить решения. Мои ответы эта не панацея на все случаи жизни. Это идея, а развитие уже лежит на каждом программисте. Как раз об этом я и учу в [Школе разработчика](https://t.me/developer_school)